# XSLT select by child node value

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to process an XML file with XSLT, where I need to select nodes by  child value. I tried to simple filter out results by regex, but maybe it is not the most elegant way to do this. I think XSLT is an universal solution to do this transform, if not please suggest me a better solution. The XML file actually look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1250"?>
<SHOP>
<SHOPITEM>
<unknown_element1></unknown_element1>
<unknown_element2></unknown_element2>
...
<YEAR>2015</YEAR>
<unknown_elementxy></unknown_elementxy>
...
</SHOPITEM>
<SHOPITEM>
<unknown_element1></unknown_element1>
<unknown_element2></unknown_element2>
...
<YEAR>2014</YEAR>
<unknown_elementxy></unknown_elementxy>
...
</SHOPITEM>
<SHOPITEM>
<unknown_element1></unknown_element1>
<unknown_element2></unknown_element2>
...
<YEAR>2015</YEAR>
<unknown_elementxy></unknown_elementxy>
...
</SHOPITEM>
</SHOP>
```

I want to keep current XML structure, but keep only nodes where  = 2015. The desidered output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1250"?>
<SHOP>
<SHOPITEM>
<unknown_element1></unknown_element1>
<unknown_element2></unknown_element2>
...
<YEAR>2015</YEAR>
<unknown_elementxy></unknown_elementxy>
...
</SHOPITEM>
<SHOPITEM>
<unknown_element1></unknown_element1>
<unknown_element2></unknown_element2>
...
<YEAR>2015</YEAR>
<unknown_elementxy></unknown_elementxy>
...
</SHOPITEM>
</SHOP>
```

`<unknown_element>` = there are many different elements in the node, the XSLT should keep current structure of the actual node. Just need to filter out nodes by `<YEAR>`.

I am trying something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes" method="xml"/>

 <xsl:template match="//SHOPITEM[YEAR=2015]">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Please show the xslt you tryied.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard I was actually not find any usable solution to my question, just this: //SHOPITEM[YEAR=2015]" -> I think this is the way to find nodes what I need.

Comment: Look up the "identity transformation" - that is the standard way to approach XSLT problems where you want to leave most of the XML alone and just change or remove specific parts of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this work for you?

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/SHOP">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="SHOPITEM[YEAR=2015]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SHOP/>

This is the output.

Comment: No, it's not (at least not with a well-formed XML input): http://xsltransform.net/nc4NzQp

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. Works nicely!

Answer (score 2):

As Ian Roberts says, you should start with the identity transform, and customize from there. This is all you need:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes" method="xml"/>

 <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <!-- Omit any shop item without YEAR = 2015 -->
 <xsl:template match="SHOPITEM[not(YEAR = 2015)]" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run on your sample input, the result is:

```
<SHOP> 
  <SHOPITEM> 
    <unknown_element1/>  
    <unknown_element2/> ...
    <YEAR>2015</YEAR>  
    <unknown_elementxy/> ...
  </SHOPITEM>  

  <SHOPITEM> 
    <unknown_element1/>  
    <unknown_element2/> ...
    <YEAR>2015</YEAR>  
    <unknown_elementxy/> ...
  </SHOPITEM> 
</SHOP>
```

Comment: Perfect, this one is good as well as @michael.hor257k's solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can nest predicates - try `//SHOPITEM[YEAR[text() = 2015]]`